# How to extract a jpi or hpi plugin to get its source code

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins plugin is a jpi or hpi format, my question is how to extract it to get the source code? Does anyone can provide any clue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `.jpi` and `.hpi` files are ZIP archives, similar to Java `.jar` or `.war` archives. But most likely they contain compiled artifacts like Java `.class` files and not the source code. You could use a Java decompiler to get source code, but most plugins are open source and it's easier to find the sources on [GitHub](https://github.com/jenkinsci).

Comment: @daspiker, thanks. Both `unzip` and `tar -xzvf` works. And as you said, I can use a Java decompiler like JD-GUI to decompile the `.class` file into source code.

Comment: not working when trying to extract using the unzip and `tar-xzvf`. ex: **tar -xzvf cloudbees-folder.jpi** gives error as not in gzip format. can you please help

Comment: use unzip, it works.
eg. unzip pluginname.jpi